# Sort a list by polar angle in counterclockwise order in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a List `L` with some terms like `range(2,3),` where the first element is the term with the lowest Y, now I need to sort the other elements of the list L (the first element will remain unchanged), I need to sort them by polar angle in counterclockwise order. If polar angle of two points is same, then I need to put the nearest term first. I defined the predicate angle2d/2:

```
angle2d(A, B, R) :-
   A =.. [_,Ax,Ay],
   B =.. [_,Bx,By],
   R is atan2((Ay-By),(Ax-Bx)).
```

that give me the counter clockwise angle between 2 points, but i didn't get how to create the predicate sort_list/2 that will sort my n-1 points (the first one element of the list will remain unchanged) by their counter clockwise angle with the first element (point) of the list.

Comment: Write `A = range(Ax,Ay)` in place of `=..`!

Comment: It is not clear to me what the sorting criterion is. After all, is it really possible that you have a **total order**?

Comment: @false "nearest term first" if that's about distance to the first element of the list, then lexicographic order will work.

Comment: @WillNess: So, please answer it!

Answer (score 1):

As a general method for sorting by some weird custom criterion, first define you `compare_custom/3` predicate, and then use it with a known sorting algorithm. In SWI you can use the `predsort/3` predicate that is defined as following:

> **predsort(+Pred, +List, -Sorted)** 
> Sorts similar to sort/2, but
>   determines the order of two terms by calling Pred(-Delta, +E1, +E2) .
>   This call must unify Delta with one of <, > or =. If the built-in
>   predicate `compare/3` is used, the result is the same as sort/2. See
>   also keysort/2.

You should also take a look at the predefined `compare/3`:

> **compare(?Order, @Term1, @Term2)**
>  Determine or test the Order between
>   two terms in the standard order of terms. Order is one of <, > or =,
>   with the obvious meaning.

Comment: The common approach is to map the list accordingly and use `keysort/2` or even just `sort/2`. For most cases, `predsort/3` is just slow.

Comment: @false There are two criterions with different priority, so it won't be straightforward (yet not impossible, of course) to combine them into a single key.

Comment: @WillNess Could you clarify your comment?

Comment: lexicographic order works. `?- keysort( [(1-3)-2, (2-1)-3, (1-2)-1], L).` =>
`L = [1-2-1, 1-3-2, 2-1-3].`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform#Comparison_to_other_languages ...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: in this particular case, two criteria are not a problem, but maybe there are cases where they are a problem? Mhmhm, looks like a question.

Comment: @false You mean when the lexicographic order won't work? I am trying to think of any, but the Gödel numbering is making it difficult....

Comment: @EugeneSh.: When mapping onto some other term that is sorted either by `keysort/2` or `sort/2`.

Comment: @false Uncountable sets? But I can't see how to apply it here :)

Comment: @false Anyway, assuming there IS such a set (which can be sorted by `predsort`, but not having the `key` mapping), we always can make the `key` function which will assign the key with the value of the index obtained  using the other sorting method. So no, I guess there is no such a (finite) sets.

Comment: decorate-sort-undecorate generally doesn't apply when we can't invent a value mapping giving the same order as the comparison sort for a given predicate, so we must actually compare the two given elements. a concrete example eludes me at the moment. something to do with the secondary test being dependent on the result of the first.

Comment: @WillNess I think it will be only in case the comparison result is depending not only on the two compared elements, but some other parameters as well (for example the result of previous comparisons). But still, you can always use the "working" sort method, and just map the values to the indices obtained from that sort.

Comment: @WillNess Some weird results will come up if we define our "less-than" predicate as a none transitive way. For example a<b, b<c, c<d, but d<a.  Than the comparison sort will give different results depending on the algorithm and the initial order.

Comment: @WillNess & Eugene: Please [see my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573197/sort-2-keysort-2-vs-predsort-3).

Comment: There is anyone who have time and can help me privately with this project please? mail me at moksud_xp@hotmail.it please.

Comment: @WillNess I don't understand how to use the predicate predsort to sort my n-1 elements by Counter Clockwise Order, can you help me writing it for my excercise please?

Comment: @EugeneSh. "you can always use the "working" sort method, and just map the values to the indices obtained from that sort." the point is to be able to *precalculate* the values, only once for each element, _before_ the sorting.

Comment: @WillNess I understand that. But it "disproves" the claim that there is no such a mapping function. Of course we can restrict this function to one argument only, then it won't be valid.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   even if we know that something exists, we still need to know how to construct it. that's two separate tasks. SWI's `sort/4` looks relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
sort_angle([], _).
sort_angle([_|[]], _).
sort_angle([_,_|[]], _).
sort_angle(List, SortedList) :-
   predsort(sort_me,[_|List], SortedList).

sort_me(<, A, B) :- angle2d(H,A,X), angle2d(H,B,Y), X<Y.
sort_me(>, A, B) :- angle2d(H,A,X), angle2d(H,B,Y), X>Y.
sort_me(=, A, B) :- angle2d(H,A,X), angle2d(H,B, Y), X=Y.
```

But I don't know, in the sort_me predicate how to tell that H is the first element of my list... how can I tell it ?

Comment: this should work in SWI: `sorted_by_angle([H|List], [H|SortedList]):- predsort(compare_me(H), List, SortedList).`, `compare_me(H,<,A,B):- angle..., angle..., (X<Y ; X==Y,  distance(H,A,N),distance(H,B,K),N<K). ...`.

Comment: @WillNess what do you mean with "angle..." ?

Comment: @WillNess what is "N" and "K" ?

Comment: @WillNess I don't understand what is the predicate distance and what it does

Comment: like angle calculates angle from point A to point B, distance is supposed to calculate the dstance. you said, when two angles are the same, the *nearest* point should go first. I assumed, nearest to the first list's element. `N` and `K` both are placed as the third argument to `distance/3`, presumably the result of this calculation. you need to write this predicate, just like you had `angle2d/3`.

Comment: Not knowing what angle2d/3 does, but I guess sort_me(D, A, B) :- angle2d(H,A,X), angle2d(H,B,Y), compare(D,X,Y). is more efficient.